# Time complexity (Big-O) of converting an array to a Set

Tags: javascript, arrays, set, big-o, computer-science

So there is multiple ways to convert an `Array` to a `Set` in JS.

*Example #2* is definitely **O(n)** since is iterating through all the elements of the array. is that the same case for *Example #1*? or JS does do some optimization in the background for us?

If yes, are there any downsides to using *Example #1*?

#### Example 1

```
const arr = [ 1, 3, 2, 3, 5 ];
const set = new Set(arr);

console.log(set);

/*
    Output: Set { 1, 3, 2, 5 }
*/
```

#### Example 2

```
const arr = [ 1, 3, 2, 3, 5 ];    
const set = new Set();
arr.map(item => set.add(item));

console.log(set);

/*
    Output: Set { 1, 3, 2, 5 }
*/
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's still `O(n)`; there's no magical way for JS to put all `n` elements in the `Set` without actually iterating through all `n` elements. The only way to get below `O(n)` would be to skip some of the elements, which is clearly impossible if all of them must be considered for inclusion in the `Set`.