# How are lists converted into sets in Python 3? And what's the performance/complexity of this conversion?

Tags: python, list, set, time-complexity, big-o

Maybe I missed something, but I couldn't find an answer to this on SO or the Python docs.

Got curious about what actually happens under the hood when we write the following code:

```
maybe_smaller_set = set(some_huge_list)
```

Since sets don't have duplicates, I imagine there's something like a list comprehension or some clever trick (maybe using `map()` or `filter()`?) that occurs to avoid iterating over everything in `some_huge_list`.

So my questions are these:

1. *How* does Python actually do this conversion from a list instance into a set instance?
2. And how costly is this conversion in terms of algorithmic complexity (ie, big-O)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python `set`s are based on hash tables. As such, insertion operations, per-element, are average/expected case amortized `O(1)`, though in pathological cases (or when the insertion requires a rehash, which becomes less and less frequent as it grows) they can approach `O(n)`.

There is no trick that can be used to avoid iterating the input `list` though; [you can't iterate all the elements without iterating all the elements in a general purpose data structure, no matter the language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63543546/364696). The expected case for constructing a `set` from a `list` will be `O(n)`, and the theoretical worst case scenario (if literally every element's hash code collides with every other element, but all elements are unique) would be `O(n²)`.

As for how Python does it, it's nothing special; internally, it's roughly equivalent to:

```
newself = set()
newself.update(iterable)
```

which is in turn roughly equivalent to:

```
newself = set()
for elem in iterable:
    newself.add(elem)
```

it [just pushes all the work to the C layer](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2e8f721c0f275d9d7c018b4a2a66f053cf34bb36/Objects/setobject.c#L1982) (on the CPython reference interpreter), bypassing the Python layer work such a loop would entail.

To correct an additional misapprehension: There are no clever tricks for `map` or `filter` either. In the best case scenario (when called with a built-in function implemented in C), both of them just avoid a little Python level overhead that the equivalent generator expression would entail. But they're fully general purpose; they use no special tricks for `list` or `set` inputs or outputs, they just steadily grind through the input iterator, mapping/filtering each element as they're requested (when the `map`/`filter` object is itself iterated). They're definitionally `O(n)`.

Comment: Fantastic (especially the reference to the underlying CPython source code).  Another question though: when you say a "general purpose data structure" would you consider something like NumPy's ndarray object as such?  

Also, is it even possible to get low level enough (say, with assembly language or machine code) so that one *can* avoid iterating over a contiguous part of memory?  My impression (which could be wrong) is that this isn't possible in principle since things seem to become imperative no matter what the language is

Comment: @KevinFlowersJr: Without specific inherent structure to the data, you can never improve on `O(n)` (and for a hash table, I can't think of anything off-hand that would get you there). There are cases where an operation like filtering can be done more efficiently when you have a sorted data structure and are extracting values within a range (the work is still technically `O(n)`, when the data is *all* within the range, but when it's typically a small subset, the ability to find the beginning and end of the range in `O(log n)` can be a significant savings).

Comment: But yes, even `ndarray` can't save you on big-O (it just does the same big-O work *much* faster by pushing it all to the C layer), and your impression is correct; the nature of transferring `n` elements from one data structure to another is inherently at least `O(n)`, simply because you have to read and write (sometimes just finding out you don't *need* to write them, as in duplicated elements being put in a `set`) `n` elements, and nothing can skip that basic work.